# How to shallow test a component with an `entryComponents`?

Tags: angular

For example, say you have the following component:

```
import { Another } from "./Another";
@Component({
    entryComponents: [
        Another
    ]
})
export class App {}
```

Even when using `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` I still have to include `Another` as part of the test declarations:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from "./App";
import { Another } from "./Another";

describe("App", () => {
  let comp: App;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<App>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ App, Another ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it("can load instance", () => {
    expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They plan on adding `EntryComponents` to the testing module interface. See issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760

For a current workaround see the Angular Material library see https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog.spec.ts#L1660.

Basically, they create a real module on the fly and then import it for the tests.

```
// Create a real (non-test) NgModule as a workaround for
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760
const TEST_DIRECTIVES = [
  ComponentWithChildViewContainer,
  PizzaMsg,
  DirectiveWithViewContainer,
  ContentElementDialog
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdDialogModule],
  exports: TEST_DIRECTIVES,
  declarations: TEST_DIRECTIVES,
  entryComponents: [ComponentWithChildViewContainer, PizzaMsg, ContentElementDialog],
})
class DialogTestModule { }
```

Now you can use `DialogTestModule`

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MdDialogModule.forRoot(), DialogTestModule]
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

My solutions is base on @kampsj solution, but I think is cleaner.

`TestBed` create a dynamic module. So, we can use a module that has the `entryComponents` ( nothing new ). My difference is that **I don't create a testModule**, **I just import the module where this Component belongs**, and is cleaner because **you don't need to add anything else ( service, other components, etc**.). This should implies if `ng serve` works then `ng test` should ( at least from the creation component perspective).

Suppose we have the follow structure:

```
app
├--- app.module.ts
├--- app.component.ts
├--- ...
├--- SomeModule2
|    ├--- somemodule2.module.ts
|    ├--- componentThatCreateDynamicsComponents
|         ├--- componentThatCreateDynamicsComponents.component.ts
|         ├--- componentThatCreateDynamicsComponents.html
|         ├--- componentThatCreateDynamicsComponents.component.spec.ts
|    ├--- someCOmponent
|         ├--- someCOmponent.component.ts
|         ├--- someCOmponent.html
|         ├--- someCOmponent.component.spec.ts
```

The `TestBed` of **componentThatCreateDynamicsComponents.component.spec.ts** should import `somemodule2` from somemodule2.module.ts. In case that you don't split your project into modules, should be the unique module that you have.

Is true that you will have Component that you don't use in that test, but it doesn't matter because is just test. And you gain flexibility when you change you testing module.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just adding DialogComponent to declarations was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a spy to override the default attach behavior:

```
it('openSearch calls to open the search overlay', () => {
    component.searchOverlayRef.hasAttached = () => false;
    spyOn(component.searchOverlayRef, 'attach').and.returnValue({
      instance: {dragStart: empty()} 
    });
    component.openSearch()
    expect(component.searchOverlayRef.attach).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Not the best test since I'm testing the implementation, but it will do until e2e tests are written to test the UI behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyDynamicComponent ],
}).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
  set: {
    entryComponents: [ MyDynamicComponent ],
  }
});
```